# tikz - apply even odd rule on mirror parts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to apply even odd rule to fill area between circle and my shape:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw[fill=gray!30,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (0.5)
        (0,-0.16) to[out=120,in=0]  (-0.131,0) to[out=180,in=70] (-0.27,-0.23) to[out=-45,in=180] (-0.15,-0.3) to[out=0,in=-135] (0,-0.18);
        \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1]
            \draw (0,-0.16) to[out=120,in=0]  (-0.131,0) to[out=180,in=70] (-0.27,-0.23) to[out=-45,in=180] (-0.15,-0.3) to[out=0,in=-135] (0,-0.18);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the mirror parts has been filled also!
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`even odd rule` only applies to the current path, not to paths that get added to an extra scope. However, you can switch on `[xscale=-1]` within a path. This allows you to get ready in time, i.e. for the StarWars Day. May the Fourth be with you!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw[fill=gray!30,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (0.5)
        (0,-0.16) to[out=120,in=0]  (-0.131,0) to[out=180,in=70] (-0.27,-0.23)
        to[out=-45,in=180] (-0.15,-0.3) to[out=0,in=-135] %(0,-0.16)
        (0,-0.16) [xscale=-1] to[out=120,in=0]  (-0.131,0) to[out=180,in=70]
            (-0.27,-0.23) to[out=-45,in=180] (-0.15,-0.3) to[out=0,in=-135]
        cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]